# Change the PolyLog branch cut in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, complex

The problem is to change the branch cut of PolyLog[2,z] function from the default half line `z=1+x, x>0` to  the new one `z=1+ Exp[I phi]x, x>0, 0<phi<2Pi.` I've already known the way to change the branch cut in the Log function:

```
LogR[z_, f1_] := Log[z Exp[-I (f1 - Pi)]] + I (f1 - Pi);
```

And I understand, that one of the possible way to do it is to integrate the PolyLog[1,z]/z function along appropriate contour lying in the domain of regularity of LogR. But this way is too slow and rough.

How can I change the PolyLog branch cut without any loss in speed and accuracy of calculations? 
And another question, which method is used by default on Wolfram to calculate PolyLog function for Abs[z]>1?

Comment: Is this really about Mathematica though, or just about the underlying math?

Comment: Yes, it is about Mathematica. I want to know a way to calculate  PolyLog[2,z] in Wolfram. For this purpose it will be useful to know which method is used by default in Wolfram to calculate PolyLog function.